# SAPUI5 bindAggregation complete for a Table

Tags: sapui5

I am binding an aggregation to a table . I couldn't find an event which is triggered after the binding is complete . There is "updateFinished" event for sap.m.List , which is exactly what I am looking for in a Table (and a dropodown). I thought of using attachRequestCompleted() on the model , but the model is used at other places where I do not want this event to trigger.

Is there anyway to trigger a event once the databinding is complete on a Table (and a dropdown)?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**update**: There is "updateFinished" event for table extended from ListBase. I am still not sure how I missed it before I posted this question. But, the question is still valid for a dropdown and TableSelectDialog controls.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you elaborate a bit more about the use case for attaching to such an event?

Comment: Hi Qualiture, I have to display something based on the selected key in a dropdown , where the selected key is bound from the server.   I could only read the value only when the binding is complete. I am using oData model.

Comment: In case of a table , lets say I want to display a 'Loading' message till the actual loading of data is complete.

Comment: See my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled upon that problem, but in a different Context.
I have a Grid layout in which I dynamically load Panels via an oData Model.

Therefore I have entered the path in my XML Grid-View element.

```
<l:Grid id="grid" content="{some path...}">...</l:Grid>
```

Now I wanted to set the grid view busy and when the data is loaded revert this.

Therefore I use the Binding of the grid view.
In the Controllers onInit method I have added:

```
this._oGrid = this.getView().byId("grid");
this.getRouter().attachRouteMatched(this._onRouteMatch.bind(this));
```

Please note that the bind method is not available in every browser. You need to apply a polyfill. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Also Bind has nothing to do with the binding :D

I needed to do this because the Binding is not available in the onInit function.

The _onRouteMatched function:

```
var oContent = this._oGrid.getBinding("content");
oContent.attachDataReceived(function(oData) {
    this._oGrid.setBusy(false);
}.bind(this));
```

Now when the data is received the busy option is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a 'loading' indicator for your table while the data is still loading (and thus not bound), I think the best approach is the following:

1. Use a dedicated JSONModel which holds only UI-specific stuff, like toggling enabled/readonly/busy/etc properties of controls.

   In your case, something like:

   ```
   var oUIModelData = {
       tableIsBusy        : false,
       //etc, things like :
       btnSubmitEnabled   : false,
       someControlVisible : true
   };
   var oUIModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   oUIModel.setData(oUIModelData);
   sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oUIModel, "UIModel");
   ```
2. In your table definition, bind the `busy` property to `{UIModel>/tableIsBusy}` and set the table's property `busyIndicatorDelay` to `0` to avoid any delays
3. Just before you do your OData service call, set the property `tableBusy` to `true`. This will immediately show the busy overlay to your table:

   ```
   sap.ui.getCore().getModel("UIModel").setProperty(tableIsBusy, true);
   //here your OData read call
   ```
4. In your OData service's `requestCompleted` (and if needed, also in `requestFailed`) event handlers, set the busy property of the UIModel back to false:

   ```
   sap.ui.getCore().getModel("UIModel").setProperty(tableIsBusy, false);
   ```

The big benefit of this approach is (IMHO) instead of relying on each control to check whether the data has been loaded, simply do it during the actual load.
And by binding these UI-related things to a (separate) model saves you from writing lots of extra code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In general you could solve the problem by using batch processing on the OData service. According to https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html:

1. Use OData model v2.

   ```
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(myServiceUrl);
   ```
2. Define a set of deferred batch groups.

   ```
   oModel.setDeferredBatchGroups(["myGroupId", "myGroupId2"]);
   ```
3. Add the batch group information to the corresponding bindings, e.g:

   ```
   {
     path:"/myEntities",
     parameters: {
       batchGroupId: "myGroupId"
     }
   }
   ```
4. All read/query actions on bindings in a certain batch group will be held back until a `.submitChanges(.)` call on the batch group is made.

   ```
   oModel.submitChanges({
     batchGroupId: "myGroupId",
     success: mySuccessHandler,
     error: myErrorHandler
   });
   ```

Use the success/error handlers to execute actions.

This rather generic approach gives you additional control such as trigger actions, grouping and event handling on the OData model.